# Pasar valores de un input y calcular ruta

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Tengo el siguiente código, estoy tratando de pasar el valor de un input textbox a una función que me calcula una ruta, el textbox esta recibiendo coordenadas desde una base de datos elcódigo es el siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('Busca_Camino').addEventListener('click', function () {
         calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
     });
 }

 function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
     var start = document.getElementById('TxtInicio').value;
     var end = document.getElementById('TxtFin').value;

     directionsService.route({
         origin: start,
         destination:end,
         travelMode: 'DRIVING'
     }, function (response, status) {
         if (status === 'OK') {
             directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
         } else {
             window.alert('No se pudo calcular la ruta debido a' + status);
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtInicio" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox> 
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtFin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta en absoluto, a qué funcion quieres pasarle el valor del input ? dónde está el input ? dónde está el código funcional? En qué es relevante que recibas los datos de una base de datos ? Qué has intentado ? Además tú código no está formateado correctamente

Comment: Gracias por responder:  traigo de una consulta  codebehind 2 valores  mismo que pinto en  los  textbox  TxtInicio y TxtFin, que quiero pasar a la funcion calculateAndDisplayRoute mediante las variables start , end. he intentado con .Value e innerHTML